# Is the boundary of a set defined using a smooth function also smooth?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $f:B_\delta(y)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth function for some $\delta>0$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Let us define the set $G:= f(B_\delta(y)) + \mathbb{R}^n_\geq$ (using the Minkowski sum).
I want to investigate whether a point $\tilde{z}:=f(\tilde{x})$ for some $\tilde{x}\in\text{int}(B_\delta(y))$ (with int the interior of the set) is a smooth boundary point of $G$, i.e. whether there exists an open neighbourhood $U=U(z)$ and a smooth function $\rho:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that fulfils
$$ U\cap G = \{z\in U: \rho(z)<0\} $$
and
$$ \frac{d}{dz} \rho(z) \neq 0\ \forall z\in U. $$
Does this hold in general or do I need additional requirements? Could you point me to a book that is treating a similar problem? I am not very familiar with manifolds and therefore struggling with looking into the relevant literature.

Could you give me a hint on how to construct a function $\rho$?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would believe that you need further assumptions. Consider a function $f:(-2;2)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $$f(t)=\begin{cases} (0,-1/2-t),& t\in (-2;-1),\\ (3/2-t,0),&t\in (1;2).\end{cases}$$ Extend $f$ to a smooth function such that $f([-1;1])$ is contained in the first quadrant. Then $G$ looks like a staircase (with a single step). So the boundary of $G$ will not be smooth in this case.

Comment: Sorry, should have been $(-3/2+t,0)$ for $t\in (1;2)$ and $f([-1;1])$ should be contained in the upper left quadrant. Also it would be enough to just require $f([-1;2))$ to be in the upper left quadrant and for some $t_0\in (-1;2)$ we have $f(t_0)=(-1,0)$, i.e. no self-intersection needed.

Comment: Even making $f$ real-analytic seems not to save us. We can construct the staircase also with $$f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, f(t)= (a,b) + (\cos(t), \sin(t))$$ for suitable $a,b$ and a suitable interval $I\subset [-\pi/2; \pi]$. Translate the circle such that it intersects the $y$-axis once at the origin and once below the origin. Pick the starting point of the interval $I$ in such a way that it corresponds to the intersection point below the origin. Pick the endpoint of $I$ in such a way that it corresponds to intersection point of the circle and $x$-axis to the left of the origin.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @SeverinSchraven, and for finding a counterexample embarrassingly fast. Do you think that convexity would help? If I see that correctly, in your examples there is always a point in the image of $f$ that is not at the boundary of $G$.

Comment: I have not quite understood your last comment. You want to assume that the image of $f$ is convex? Or that $G$ is convex? None of this will help us. Consider $$f:(0;1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2, f(t)=(0,0).$$ Then $G=\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^2$ which does not have a smooth boundary, despite $G$ being convex (and the image of $f$ is contained in the boundary of $G$). Also the entire image of $f$ is at the point where boundary is not smooth.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you could share with us what's the goal you have in mind. This looks like the kind of question that does not work in general, but might be true for some specific applications that one has in mind.